# How to create a inline function but with external linkage?

Tags: c

I'm sorry for my English, actually I am not an English speaker. My question is the following: How could you create a inline function but with external linkage? In the book that I'm currently studying C, says that you can create an inline function but with external linkage with the help of a header file and a source file. Could anyone help me to clarify and tell me also why does this process work? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

> How could you create a inline function but with external linkage?

These details are covered in section 6.7.4 of the current C language specification (C17).  It's important here to understand that the spec uses two similar terms, attributing different meaning:

---

**Inline function**

> A function declared with an `inline` function specifier is an *inline function*.

(C17 6.7.4/6)

These are all declarations (only) of inline functions:

```
inline int do_something(int x);
extern inline int do_something_else(int x);
static inline int yada_yada_yada(int x);
```

---

**Inline definition**

> If all of the file scope declarations for a function in a translation unit include the `inline` function specifier without `extern`, then the definition in that translation unit is an *inline definition*.

(C17 6.7.4/7)

This is an inline definition of an inline function with (by default) external linkage:

```
inline int do_something(int x) {
    return x + 1;
}
```

On the other hand, this is an external definition of an inline function with external linkage:

```
extern inline int do_something(int x) {
    return x + 1;
}
```

---

> In the book that I'm currently studying C, says that you can create an inline function but with external linkage

Your wording suggests that you think there's some kind of conflict between `inline`-ness and external linkage.  There is not. All you need for an inline function with external linkage is to declare a function with the `inline` specifier and without `static`.

But remember always that linkage is primarily about identifiers (names), not directly about the objects and functions they identify.  The catch comes in when we consider that C requires there to be exactly one external definition
corresponding to each function identifier that is used, anywhere in the program where it has external linkage, to call the function it identifies.  It does not matter whether there are inline definitions available too.

> with the help of a header file and a source file.

Your book presumably has a specific implementation model in mind.  It is not strictly necessary to involve a header file. However,  if you want to use the function in multiple translation units then you wanted a declaration in a header file and a definition in a source file anyway.  And if you didn't want that, then you would be better off giving it internal linkage.

So the trick here is that to provide for actually inlining the function implementation in all translation units, the header needs to be able to provide a definition of it.  But not an external definition, because there can be only one of those for each function.  Instead, an inline definition.  But you still need an external definition *somewhere*.

A non-inline external function would normally be set up something like this:

**non_inline.h**

```
// ...
// external declaration (only) of do_something
int do_something(int x);
// ...
```

**non_inline.c**

```
#include "non_inline.h"
// ...
// external definition of do_something
int do_something(int x) {
   return x * 2;
}
// ...
```

There are several variations on how you might do an inline version, but this one is fairly clean and non-repetitive:

**inline.h**

```
#ifndef SOMETHING_EXTERN
#define SOMETHING_EXTERN
#endif
// ...
// external declaration (only) of do_something
SOMETHING_EXTERN int do_something(int x);
// ...
```

**inline.c**

```
#define SOMETHING_EXTERN extern
#include "inline.h"
// ...
```

Here the function definition is in the header.  Most translation units will not define `SOMETHING_EXTERN` except via the header, which defines it to nothing.  In those translation units, the header will provide an inline definition.  But there is one, chosen translation unit that defines `SOMETHING_EXTERN` to `extern` before `#include`ing the header, so that in that translation unit, the header will provide an external definition of the function (which is nevertheless still an inline function as the C spec uses that term).